# How to stretch the height of a webview in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I got a page where I have a grid within a textblock and a webview.

I can't find a way to let the webview filling the page, event with the "*" or the horizontal strech.

I had to put a minHeight to see the webview because if I set no height, it's not visible (I guess height is 0).

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" >
        <Grid  >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="title" MaxLines="1" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <WebView MinHeight="600"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
                         x:Name="webview"  
                         Margin="10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Here is my cs code

```
webview.NavigateToString("<HEAD>" +
                    "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #fff; background-color: #000; overflow-x: hidden;" + fontSize + "}</style>" +
                    "<TITLE>title</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>" + text + "</BODY>");
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove the stackpanel & set the Height to Auto

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="title" MaxLines="1"
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                   Margin="10" TextAlignment="Left"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" 
                   FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Grid Background="Black"
              Margin="10"
              Grid.Row="1">
            <WebView ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
                     x:Name="webview"  
                     Margin="10" 
                     Height="Auto" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Have you try to clean the solution and rebuild it?

Comment: I mean I was doing the margin from he stackpanel, I removed it and also removed it from the webviewso I dont have a white border (the main grid is white and grid row 1 should be black)

Comment: Check if putting webview inside grid solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" >
    <Grid  >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="title" MaxLines="1" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <WebView MinHeight="600" Grid.Row="1"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
                     x:Name="webview"  
                     Margin="10" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```